# Changing an invalid input after its caught with an exception Java

Tags: java, exception

So I'm attempting to change a value of a test score after an exception is thrown (gets thrown if value is above 100 or below 0), currently, it just exits the program after the invalid number is entered.

Exceptions class

```
public class InvalidTestScore extends Exception {
    public InvalidTestScore() {
    super("Error: Invalid grade");
  }

public InvalidTestScore(int grade) {
    super("Error: " + grade + " is invalid!");
 }

}
```

Runnable class

```
 /*
gets the test scores
*/
public static int[] inputScores(int amount) throws InvalidTestScore {
    int grades[] = new int[amount];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for ( int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please input the score for test: " + (i+1));
       int input = scanner.nextInt();
       while(input < 0 || input > 100) {
           throw new InvalidTestScore(input);
           //reinput number
       }
       grades[i] = input;
    }
    return grades;
}
```

**How do I allow for the user to change the value of the bad grade?**

Comment: I have a feeling that this question was initiated by an assignment that is for teaching you how to use exceptions. If so, you will want to separate your concerns -- have one method that is for validating the input, and that throws the exception if the input is invalid, and have another method that gets the input from the user within a while loop that loops based on a boolean, that calls the above method *within a try/catch* block, and then if valid (if the exception is not thrown) changes a boolean so that the while loop exits.

Comment: If so, this is all well explained in most any exceptions tutorial and in similar questions on this site

Comment: Thank you so much! I searched for a little while before posting, and didn't find this. I appreciate you very much. PS: your name is funny